# How to pass multiple values in setArguments() and render view?

Tags: views, 8

I want to pass multiple values in setArguments() and render view. I'm using below code but it's showing only 1 value instead of multiple.

```
 public function _ajax_generate_request_view(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView('play_center_generate_request');
  $view->setArguments(array('23','46'));
  $view->execute();
  $render_view = $view->render();
  $ajax_response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#view_wrappers', $render_view));
  return $ajax_response;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends if you need OR or AND clause :

```
$view->setArguments(array('23,46'));
$view->setArguments(array('23+46'));
```

One string for each argument.

Comment: Working....!!!!